# How to dynamically change source of image based on current values in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that currently displays a leaderboard and a picture. The picture is an image of whoever is currently in 1st place on the leaderboard. The html for this is as follows:

```
<div id="leaderboardDiv">
<h1>Leaderboard</h1>
<table id="leaderboard">
    <tr><th></th><th>Owner</th><th>Points</th></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Barry</td><td>166</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Tom</td><td>161</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Laura</td><td>159</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td>Shane</td><td>153</td></tr>
</table>
```

```
        <div id="pictureDiv">
            <img src="/Content/Images/Barry.jpg" style="width:150px;height:200px" />
        </div>      
</div>
```

Now I'd like to create a javascript function so that the image changes dynamically when the first place on the leaderboard changes. The Images folder contains a jpg of each of the people on the leaderboard with a file name that matches their leaderboard name exactly.

Would it be possibly to write something in jQuery or javascript that could dynically alter the src of the img tag so that it matches whoever is in 1st place in the table? First place can be ideintified by being the content of the second column of the first  row of the table.

Comment: What makes the first place of leaderboard change? If it is only data from server, then you should handle it server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first person's name from the leaderboard:

```
var winnerName=$("#leaderboard tr td:eq(1)").text();
```

Now change the image tag SRC attribute:

```
$("#pictureDiv img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/"+winnerName+".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the `attr()` function in jquery:

```
var firstPlaceGuy = $("table#leaderboard tr").first();

//get the data-img-src attribute (form the below html code)
var imageSRC = $(firstPlaceGuy).data("imgSrc");

//set the "src" attribute in the <img> tag
$("#pictureDic img").attr("img", imageSRC);
```

Also, add some information to the first place guy's html tag:

```
<tr data-img-src="derp.png"> ... </tr>
```